# discord.py - discord.Member.reactions object giving empty list

Tags: python, discord.py

```
def e_check(reaction):
  for x in reaction:
    if x in ["\u0031\ufe0f\u20e3", "\u0032\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0033\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0034\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0035\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0036\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0037\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0038\ufe0f\u20e3"]:
      return True

fight_embed = [dm_embed_user1, dm_embed_user2] # dm_embed_user1 = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

for x in figth_embed:
    confirmation = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=e_check(x.reactions), timeout = 15)
    if confirmation:
      print(x.reactions) # it gives empty list
      for emoji in x.reactions:
        print("worked") # it doesn't prints worked as x.reactions is a empty list
```

these are the reactions on the embed

[image]

Why is the x.reactions is an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dm_embed_user1` and `dm_embed_user2` are the messages that you just sent, before you added emojis to them, so getting their reactions will always return an empty list.

To get the list of reaction, you need to use what `wait_for` returns. With `reaction_add` events, `confirmation` will be a list of two elements:

- The reaction that was added
- The member that added a reaction

Your check is incomplete, it needs two arguments, `reaction` and `user` (replace `message.author` to `ctx.author` if you're in a command):

```py
def e_check(reaction, user):
  flag = str(reaction.emoji) in ["\u0031\ufe0f\u20e3", "\u0032\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0033\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0034\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0035\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0036\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0037\ufe0f\u20e3","\u0038\ufe0f\u20e3"]
  return flag and user == message.author
```

Finally, your loop would look like this:

```py
for embed in figth_embed:
    reaction, member = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=e_check(x.reactions), timeout = 15)

    for emoji in reaction.message.reactions:
        print("worked")
```

PS: If your user doesn't react in time, it will raise a `asyncio.TimeoutError`.

Comment: what is message in  reaction.message.reactions

Comment: it gives error saying message not defined so I added message as the parameter but then it gives error required two more positional arguments

Comment: Is the code you gave in a `on_message` event or in a command?

Comment: it is a command, I now replaced message.author to ctx.author but it still gives an error saying 1 positional argument missing